# Cannot find the core dump from an abort due to seg fault on Linux from a docker image

Tags: docker, core-dump

This is running in a docker image. My yml includes the following:

```
- ulimit -c unlimited 
- ulimit -a
```

Running several robot tests and one (in the middle) outputs:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped) != Writing [1000h,0h] on Node 1h on interface CAN1
```

Only happens on the build machine docker image so I need to get this dump. It does not appear to be in the executable directory and I've ran the following search:

```
- find / -name "*core.*"
```

from yml, which finds nothing relevant. Any ideas? Is docker artifacts or something similar cleaning this?